# Is it true that pheromones can synchronize a household of women's menstruation cycles? How? Why? Who's cycle is dominant?

Tags: medical-myths, pheromones, dominant-gene, recessive-gene, body-odor

Is it true that pheromones can synchronize a household of women's menstruation cycles? How? Why? Who's cycle is dominant? How long does it take for it to work? Or is this all a medical myth?